# How can I use an existing product database with parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to create a mobile app for a shopping company. I was planning on using Parse for the backend. The company already has a database with all of their product information. Can I route this product information(pictures, pricing) through Parse and query product information from there? I have never used Parse before, but it seems like a good tool I would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to 'route' the product information through Parse.  It has to exist in a Parse Class.

If you need to maintain the data in both the database and Parse, you could create a script that sync's the data between the two.  If you're going this route, I recommend having a GUID column in the database that you can use to compare against your data in Parse; if the GUID doesn't exist in the Parse Class, copy the row over.  Otherwise, skip it.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I want to be able to pull the existing information and use it in the app from the existing database. What I gathered from Parse is that it is great for managing data created in the app itself (logins, accounts), but I couldn't find much on integrating it with other databases.

Comment: @NickHelvig Did you find solution to your question ? I am also having same scenario where I want to be able to pull the existing information and use it in the app from the existing database. If you find something then let me know.